# Aliasing a function object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, extjs3

**Disclaimer:** I am using ExtJS 3, but I don't think it's very relevant to the question, outside of the common use of it's namespacing function.

I have a *singleton* that's declared in a really long namespace like this:

```
Ext.ns("REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE");

var Singleton = (function() {   
    var foo = {
        bar: "baz"
    }; 

    var privateFunction = function(param){
        // ...
        return foo;
    };

    var single = Ext.extend(Object, {
        constructor: function(config) {
            Ext.apply(this, config);
        },
        otherFunction: privateFunction,     
        publicFunction: function (someObject){
            // do stuff with someObject
        }
    });

    return single;

})();
// Make it a singleton
REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE.Singleton = new Singleton();
```

I use it in other modules via calls like `REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE.Singleton.otherFunction();` and `REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE.Singleton.publicFunction(myObject);` .  I'm wondering if I can swap out those calls by setting up the client module with an alias to the singleton, i.e. `var singleton = REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE.Singleton;` , so that I can call `singleton.otherFunction();`.  I'm wondering if this is an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) , or if there are any pitfalls (memory?) I might run into through this usage.

Thanks StackOverflow!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I can swap out those calls by setting up the client module with an alias to the singleton

Yes, you can.

> I'm wondering if this is an anti-pattern , or if there are any pitfalls (memory?) I might run into through this usage.

No, there aren't any that I can think of and it is faster than calling the fully-qualified version.

[Local Alias Pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/05/17/javascript-local-alias-pattern.aspx)

---

**Example:**

```
function somefunc(){
    var singleton = REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE.Singleton;

    singleton.publicFunction();
};
```

Or:

```
(function somfunc(singleton){

}(REALLY.REALLY.LONG.NAMESPACE.Singleton));
```

---

**Test Results:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jMg9A/

Comment: @Xander - Great example on the IEF!

Comment: @alvincrespo Haha, good call... Xander, I hadn't even thought of adding it into the arguments passed to my closure.  **D'OH!**

Comment: Xander, I have to give it to you.  Including the test was awesome.  I actually get some pretty wild results, and I was wondering if this is what you meant to link to : http://jsfiddle.net/jMg9A/2/  .  Given this result, it looks like the local variable is even faster, is that possible?

Comment: @alvincrespo I figured I should mention you both on this one... Using an `n` value of `90000000` gives me even more unexpected results.  The local variable appears orders of magnitude faster --> `using window.one.two.three.four.five[fubar] : 10381ms` *vs.* `using a[fubar] : 90ms`

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with creating a reference to the original "object". In many cases we create a namespace to organize our code, but of course, this can lead to really long namespaces that we really don't wish to reference later, thus creating a local reference to that namespace is an excellent idea so that you can change it in one place instead of various places.

I don't really see an ant-pattern here, instead I see an opportunity to make it simpler for yourself and probably a little more manageable from a developer standpoint.